# php sqlite3Result

Tags: php, sqlite

How would the following fail:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('SOMETHING')");
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

What would be a scenerio when: `!$result == true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Database file is not opened or not writable.
2. `sometable` does not exist.
3. A [conflict](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) occurs.

Comment: If some table doesn't exist, it would fail with a warning + a fatal error. Database is not writable should error out on `open`, idk about a conflict, though.

Comment: If a missing table causes a fatal error (i.e. the PHP script aborts) this is a flaw in the design of the sqlite3 extension. Database might be writable on `open`, but that might change during the execution of the script (not necessarily by the script itself, see [Time-of-check-to-time-of-use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check-to-time-of-use)).

Answer (score 0):

1. If 'sometable' has more than 1 not-null column with no defaults.
   see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html
   first bullet, second sentence